# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[xxx,xxx] doesn't always mean invalid input XML?

Tags: java, xml

When parsing a XML file using Java and getting an error shown below, would there be any possible cause other than an invalid input XML that makes this specific exception be thrown?

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[xxx,xxx]
```

Comment: I'm not talking about any particular XML file

Comment: You could read the docs of `XMLStreamException`.  If it doesn't specifically mention that it can only happen in the case of parse errors, then I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: yes, I have already read it. But  it does not really give you an insight into what exactly could trigger the exception. "This Exception class is used to report well-formedness errors as well as unexpected processing conditions"